# How are rubberized stair treads done when there is an open landing?

Tags: stairs

I want to add rubberized stair treads to a staircase.

However, at the bottom of the staircases is a landing that is open on two sides.

Since the stair tread material I have seen just has a lip on one side, how is this handled? Do they miter the landing lip somehow?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the steps? Stairs come in hundreds of architectural varieties, each with its own rubberized covering possibilities.

Comment: Do the rubberized mats cover the full width of the treads? Mine leave a little exposed wood on each side

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri The corners of the landing are square.

Comment: Are the exposed corners of the landing treads square or rounded off?

Comment: it usually harder to slip on a landing than a tread, so might not be needed.